# Wordpress: Remove link in the_tags

Tags: php

How do I remove the link generated by the_tags?

This is what I use today: `<?php the_tags( '', '', '' ); ?>`

That results in the tags assigned to the post. But I want to remove the link. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use following code:

```
<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->name . ' '; 
  }
}
?>
```

More details: http://wpeden.com/tipsntuts/getting-list-of-tags-for-a-post/

Answer (score 0):

Get the tag list, and then strip the tags.

```
<?php
if (is_single()) { the_post(); rewind_posts();
  $articletags = strip_tags(get_the_tag_list('',', ',''));
  echo $articletags;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a better way of doing so.

Filter the links, by stripping/removing all HTML tags from all post tag links.

```
add_filter('term_links-post_tag', function($links) {
    return array_map('wp_strip_all_tags', $links);
});
```

Then call `the_tags`, `get_the_tag_list` or `get_the_terms_list` to retrieve the post tags.

**Note:** this removes the links from post tags everywhere when called from one of the above functions, so also in your feed.